# Strange values in registers and call parameters

Tags: objective-c, windbg, gnustep

I have a very old program, that crashed. While debugging the crash with Windbg, that I've installed as the post-mortem debugger, I noticed that one of the registers was set to a strange value:

`rdx=00000000`**`deadface`**

Stack trace of the thread that caused the crash (access violation) contained some suspicious value as well:

`objc_1!objc_msg_lookup+0x29:
00000000 6784a4c5 488b4a38        mov     rcx,qword ptr [rdx+38h] ds:00000000`**`dead`**`fb06=????????????????`

I've obtained the first value from register listings that was included in the output of the `!analyze -v` command. The second was produced by the command to list stack of the failing thread (`~9k`).

Is Windbg trying to tell me something by putting such values into registry and stack dumps, or am I just a victim of some old test code or a hoax (or is it just a coincidential value)?

The program is written in obj-c and runs an old versions of GNUstep and obj-c runtime.

Comment: There is a memory pattern `deadbeef` which stands for memory deallocated by `HeapFree()`

Comment: Thanks, good hint. Just found that `deadface` is a pattern used by GNUstep for a similar purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out it is the GNUstep way to tell that the program tried to send a message (=invoke a method) on an object that was already deallocated.

If an object is deallocated, GNUstep sets `0xdeadface` as a value of the object's `isa` pointer. `isa` pointer referes to the class the object is an instance of; objective-c runtime uses this pointer to resolve object's methods when dispatching messages to it.

Therefore, every attempt to send a message to a deallocated object results in a segfault, that, if trapped in a debugger, usually shows `0xdeadface` in a register or on stack.